# show that, every positive rational number can be expressed as sum of consecutive rational number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\ne 0$ and $u\in \mathbb{Z^*}$

$S_{u}(n)$ is a number defined  as

$$S_{u}(n)= \frac{1}{n}+( \frac{1}{n}+1)+(\frac{1}{n}+2)+...+(\frac{1}{n}+u)$$

$$= \sum_{i=0}^{u}(\frac{1}{n}+i)$$

$$=\frac{(u+1)(2+un)}{2n}$$

**Question**

> > Can we show, every positive rational number can be expressed as $S_{u}(n)$?

Comment: I can't even see how any rational number between 0 and 1 that isn't of the form $1\over n$ could be expressed like this.

Comment: can you explain what is **consecutive rational number**?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio If you read the body of the question and not just the title, you will most likely find out.

Comment: @MatthewDaly $n$ can be negative, so $S_2(-5) = \frac 3 5$ and $S_2(-6) = \frac 2 3$ etc. But you are correct that this trick doesn't work for *mos*t rational numbers between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Correction : $S_1(-5)=\frac 3 5$ and $S_1(-6)=\frac 2 3$. "Off by one" error.

Comment: @Wojowu I know what does he mean, but I want to have a more specific explain and not just show in the body. Also, he can't create a new term "consecutive rational number" without any explain.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio yes, you are right. Actually I just expresse, not going deeper for an official definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that there are no integer values for $u$ and $n$ such that $S_u(n)=\frac 4 7$.

If $n \in \{-1,1\}$ then $S_u(n) \in \mathbb{Z} \space \forall u$. But $\frac 4 7 \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $|n| \ge 2$.

If $|n| \ge 2$ then $\frac 1 n \ge -\frac 1 2$ so $S_2(u) = 3 + \frac 3 n \ge \frac 3 2$ and $S_u(n) \gt S_2(n) \space \forall u \gt 2$. But $\frac 4 7 < \frac 3 2$ so $u=0$ or $u=1$.

If $S_0(n) = \frac 4 7$ then $\frac 1 n = \frac 4 7 \Rightarrow n = \frac 7 4 \not \in \mathbb{Z}$

If $S_1(n) = \frac 4 7$ then $1 + \frac 2 n = \frac 4 7 \Rightarrow n = -\frac {14} 3 \not \in \mathbb{Z}$